# Warning: Shallow renderer has been moved to react-test-renderer/shallow

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-test-renderer

I am getting following warnings while executing my unit test cases with jest in React app:

> Warning: Shallow renderer has been moved to
> react-test-renderer/shallow. Update references to remove this warning.
>
> Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update
> references to remove this warning.

I have used shallow from enzyme. Installed all needed dependencies as well but still getting this warning though the test cases execute fine. Below is the package json snapshot:

```
"jest": "^22.1.4",
"enzyme": "^3.2.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-15.4": "^1.0.5",
"react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1"
```

I found the similar issue on git [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/876), but the conversation is so cumbersome and unfruitfull with no clear solution. I wont be able to update React so looking for the fix for v15.1.

Here is my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Button from '../src/component/Button';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Button />
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
describe('Button', () => {
    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        mount(<Button />);
    });
});
```

Comment: did You find solution for this problem?

Comment: @VasylGutnyk nope mate!